# Blocking PSH flags on enp9s0 blocks everything

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

First let me clarify that enp9s0 is my ethernet device connected to my ISP modem, an ancient Thomson DWG874.

When I use this iptables rule:

```
$IPT4 -A INPUT -i $ETHIF -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH PSH -j DROP
```

I can't fetch anything from the internet, I can fetch my ISP modem web interface, but the page does not render right, as forms and other html elements are not rendered ṕropperly .

Also with this rule:

```
$IPT4 -A INPUT -i $ETHIF -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags URG URG -j DROP
```

Does not work.

Both rules tested individually and together, same results, BUT if I change the "-i" input interface to "all", everything works just fine, with these two lines bellow :

```
$IPT4 -A INPUT -i all -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags URG URG -j DROP
$IPT4 -A INPUT -i all -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH PSH -j DROP
```

There are just too many hacking attempts so I'm trying to block it on that interface.

So my question is:

There is nothing wrong with the rules, so what is going on?

Comment: I could use the rules by doing something like this:

```
$IPT4 -A INPUT -i all -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH PSH -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

and 

$IPT4 -A INPUT -i all -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags URG URG -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```